# How to get rid of the bar between splitted windows in vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

When I use `:vs` to split the screen in vim, there is a bar between the two windows that distracts me and uses up some screen real estate. I have seen in screenshots that it can be removed, but how?

Ideally it would look something like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get rid of it completely. Only highlight it in such a color so it fits with the background / foreground, and you don't notice it. But it will still be there.

Comment: would be okay. I'd like it to have the color of the background of the line numbers. Do you know how I can achieve that with the solarzied-color-theme?

Comment: @AME - Solarized could be a bit special (it's actually a few schemes wrapped up in one) but :hi Vertsplit gui=NONE guibg=fg guifg=bg should do it. I think :) If it doesn't work just reverse the bg and fg.

Comment: @AME - Yup, that approach will get you your screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

```
:set fillchars-=vert:\|
```

That will get rid of the character, but there will always be a one-character border, like the statusline that separates horizontal window splits. While it would be possible to draw a pixel-thin line in GVIM, Vim tries to be uniform in all its incarnations.

You can change the color via:

```
:highlight VertSplit gui=reverse guifg=Red
```

Comment: Note: for Neovim, `VertSplit` is [deprecated](https://neovim.io/doc/user/deprecated.html#_highlights). Use `WinSeparator` instead.